# Android get data from sql lite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

 private static final String SAMPLE_DB_NAME = "JBook";
 private static final String SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME = "Info";

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     SQLiteDatabase sampleDB =  this.openOrCreateDatabase(SAMPLE_DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        sampleDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                " (LastName VARCHAR, FirstName VARCHAR," +
                " Rank VARCHAR);");
        sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                " Values ('Kirk','James, T','Captain');");
        sampleDB.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "DB Created!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
```

this program has no errors.
I want to display the values via in textview("krick,james,Captain") while button clicked.Make it simple program and make comments.Plese provide simple codes.

Comment: use a listview and a cursor adapter

Comment: the best way to display data is by using listview and cursor adapter as also said by Raghunandan...

Answer (score 0):

Read this:
[How to retrieve the data from my SQLite database and display them to a textView](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/632942/How-to-reatrive-the-data-from-my-SQLite-database-a)

Hope this helps you.

```
SQLiteDatabase sampleDB =  this.openOrCreateDatabase(SAMPLE_DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
Cursor returnCursor = sampleDB.rawQuery("select * from " + SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME, null);

if(returnCursor != null && returnCursor.moveToFirst()){
String txt1 = returnCursor.getString(0);
String txt2 = returnCursor.getString(1);
String txt3 = returnCursor.getString(2);
returnCursor.close(); 
}
```

I haven't tried the code, it may have syntax error.

Comment: Why -1, please put your comments??

Comment: @JeyBoss: is it solving your problem?